# Android : Count Number of Clicks (or events) by all users

Tags: android, web-services, analytics

I'm writing an `android` app, the app interacts with online **DB**. Now I want to count number of clicks (or other events) from all users. I don't know how to do it? 
I can write a **web service** and call that when user clicks the `button`, but this solution is best practice?

Thanks

Comment: have you look to google analytics for android https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ ?

Comment: @sonic Thanks, could you introduce me an alternative for this?

Comment: I don't know any libraries who do what google analytics does. But you can implement a workaround yourself. I think you should not try to call your webservice every time the button is clicked. Instead store in databse each time where the button is clicked. Then in a background service, whever you have network connectivity, send that info to your webservice (and add a flag or delete the successfully send data).